# Getting Facebook to pull an Image from a redirect URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a rather large site that features travel properties.

Each property has its own Property ID #

When a user posts to Facebook using our full property url Facebook pulls the featured property image correctly.

However our urls are long for each property. So we created a shortened redirect for all. www.domain.com/propertyID#.

When a user posts the redirect version on Facebook it fails to scrape an image because the redirect does not have the og:image data.

Is it possible to have Facebook pull the image when the redirect URL is posted? We do not want the redirect URL's to be indexed.

Comment: How are you redirecting? The FB scraper follows proper 301 redirects. Does the long URL have the correct og:url value set? What does the Facebook debug tool say about this?